# Null object to toggle volume in After Effects?

Tags: after-effects

Null objects don't have volume controls, but I'd like to control many audio layers in my timeline at once.

Anyone know of a way to adjust volume or toggle mute on a bunch of layers without having to precompose them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Add a Slider to your Null Object.
- Alt-click on the stopwatch next to the one of the volume controls that you want to control.

This will open the Expressions box for the volume control, and a pick-whip icon will appear.

- Drag from the pick-whip to the Slider in your Null.

Some code will appear in the Expressions box, something like:

```
temp = thisComp.layer("Null 1").effect("Slider Control")("Slider");
[temp, temp]
```

The numbers on the volume control will turn pink to indicate that they are being controlled by an expression.

- Now move the slider on the null, and the volume should change on the audio track.

To do this to multiple audio tracks, just follow the same process.

Here is a screen shot to illustrate this:

[image: screenshot]